# socket.io-client: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, browser-sync

I'm trying to adapt a [socket.io tutorial's example](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) to my code, using the npm package [`socket.io-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client).

After this attempt I've obtained the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1451092774034-0 responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Bellow the code:

### the client

*exactly as prescribed by the package developer*

```js
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('news', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', {
    my: 'data'
  });
});
```

### the server

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/app'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I suppose the problems is related with the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/app'))` . However, I don't know how to use this suspection to workaround the problem.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The related problem has to do with some conflicts with browsersync, as reported in [this github's issue](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/223)